# Prove for some $n$, $f^{n+1}=f^n$ and that Y is bijective.

Tags: functions, proof-verification, proof-explanation

Are these sufficient to show what is being asked? If you could confirm or provide a more efficient way to do so I would greatly appreciate it.

> Let $X$ be a finite set and $f:X\rightarrow X$ be a function. Let $f^1=f$ and if $f^n$ has been defined for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ then set $f^{n+1}=f\circ f^n$
>
> a)Prove for some $n$, $f^{n+1}=f^n$

Let $Range(f^{n+1})=Range(f^{n})$

$Range(f^{k+1})\subseteq Range(f^{c})$

Let $y\in Range(f^{k+1})$

Then there exists an $x$ s.t. $y=f^{k+1}(x)=f^k(f(x))\in Range(f^{k})$

> b)Set $Y=Range(f^n)$ and $g=f\cap (Y\times Y)$ so that g is a function on $Y$.
> Prove that Y is bijective.

Set $Y=Range(f^k)$ where $Range(f^{k+1})=Range(f^{k})$

$I=f\cap (Y\times Y)$, $I=f| Y:Y$ is surjective

Therefore Y is bijective.

Comment: Y is a set. What do you mean by "Y is bijective"?

Answer (score 1):

In the present formulation it is not true. Let $X=\{0,1\}$, $f(0)=1$, $f(1)=0$. Then $f^{2k}=id$, $f^{2k+1}=f\neq id$.